Error when switch composer 1 to composer 2

PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of
Magento\ComposerRootUpdatePlugin\Plugin\Commands\OverrideRequireCommand::execute(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface
$input, Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface $output) must
be compatible with
Composer\Command\RequireCommand::execute(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface
$input, Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface $output)

i am using magento 2.4.3-p1 and composer 1, now when i update composer to 2 and run composer -v it gives me the above error

what is your PHP version?

Magento 2.4.3 is quite an old version. Using composer 1 is needed I believe. You can switch composer version quite easily even if you run multiple sites on your server.
It seems possible to use both composer version simultaneously, see https://joostvanveen.com/run-composer-1-and-2-simultaniously

composer self-update --2
use this command
